# Get another tab's viewcontroller variable in current tab bar - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a tabBarController with below hierarchy

TabBarController

- Tab 1 -> Contains Navigation Controller(NavController1) -> ViewController1 -has--> ContainerView --contains--> DisplayedViewControllerTab1 (this is my tab1 view controller displayed)

Variable dataForVC1 is in DisplayedViewControllerTab1

- When user taps Tab3 (DisplayedViewControllerTab3), I'm trying to get value of dataForVC1 to pass to tab3 viewController

So far I've tried this

In in TabBarController - didSelect method

```
    var data: ModelData?  
    if let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] as? NavController1, 
       let childNavVC = navController.children.first as? ViewController1 {
       //Get container view
       let conView = childNavVC.containerView. //This is outlet

      //Looking for something like this - struck here
      if let displayedVC1 = "Container view's VC as? DisplayedViewControllerTab1 {
         data = displayedVC1.dataForVC1
     }
}
```

Kindly advice how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to hustle around with container views. In your `ViewController1` simply add references to the DisplayedViewControllerTab1 or other vc's you need and then access them directly.

Your VC code would look something like this.

```swift
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
   //...
   var displayedVC1: DisplayedViewControllerTab1?
   //...
}
```

And then your code now:

```swift
var data: ModelData?  
if let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] as? NavController1, 
   let childNavVC = navController.children.first as? ViewController1 {
     data = childNavVC.displayedVc1
}
```

P.S. For convenience, if you have your own TabBarController class you can add all the references you need when the controller is created or simply have computed properties, so you don't need to go deep in the hierarchy all the time.

In your `TabbarViewController` class:

```swift
var myViewController1: MyViewControllerOne? {
   return (viewControllers[0] as? NavController)?.children.first as? MyViewControllerOne
}
var myViewController2: MyViewControllerTwo? {
   return (viewControllers[1] as? NavController)?.children.first as? MyViewControllerTwo
}
```

Comment: i have segue from container to DisplayedViewControllerTab1. If I add this "var displayedVC1: DisplayedViewControllerTab1? " then my displayedVC1 will be nil until i assign some value

Comment: Yeah, but that's okay? You won't have navigation data until that point either so I don't see how that might be an issue.